# Android backbutton exits my application when onPause/onResume was triggered (home button)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a activity **A** that calls activity **B**.
When in activity **B** I press the back button I get to activity **A** again which is fine!

But!

When I am in activity **B** and press the home button and then again return to the app pressing the home button again an selecting my app and then press the back button, my application exits.

What I suspect is that my activity stack is probably deleted by the GC onPause method?
How can I avoid this behaviour?

P.S. I dont use onFinish() method.

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: thats very weird. can you share your code, it should actually go to activity A even you press home and get to the application

Comment: This question should not be tagged with java-me. Android has nothing to do with JavaME.

Answer (score 0):

I started the activity B in the onTouch listener which gets triggered 2 times, one on key down and one on key up.

You just have to check one action on up or down....

Do it like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
....
```